# Class instance in youtube API and general

Tags: php, youtube-api

I'm doing some upload with youtube API. In their developer section google http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php.html first says to do this:

```
$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();
```

then in the AuthSub section to do this:

```
$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube($httpClient, $applicationId, $clientId, $developerKey);
```

then in the direct upload to do this:

```
$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube($httpClient);
```

all this are from ZendGdata libraries.

now, aren't those the same things? Do I really need to make a third instance when I have already done it a second time with $httpClient in it?

How do you call $httpClient, class parameter or?

Comment: Could you please post links to these pages so that we can read them ourselves?

Comment: of course, here it is: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php.html#Direct_Upload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I haven't ever used this API)

The guide says:

> Before you can perform any operations with the YouTube Data API, you must initialize a Zend_Gdata_YouTube object as shown in the following example. (Most of the method examples in this guide also operate on an instance of Zend_Gdata_YouTube.) Please note that all API operations that do not involve retrieving public content will require authentication.

So, if you are planning on using the `Zend_Gdata_YouTube` object for something that requires authentication, you'll need to include all four parameters. Otherwise, it looks like uploads still require the `$httpClient` parameter.

*Aren't those all the same thing?*

Well, yes. In the most general case, you need to supply all of the parameters, but the API developers knew that a lot of the information isn't necessary, so they let you omit it if it's not needed.

*Do I really need a third instance?*

I expect no. I don't think you need a 2nd instance either. If you need to do more than one thing with your `Zend_Gdata_YouTube` object, just reuse it. Make sure that when you initialize it, you choose the constructor that includes all the necessary information for any use you're planning.

*How do you call $httpClient, class parameter or?*

I don't know what you're asking here. It looks like you have two options: AuthSub or ClientLogon. Look [here](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php.html#Authentication) for more info.

Comment: *I expect no. I don't think you need a 2nd instance either.* 
first instance is general for starting the use of API. the second is specific for authorization, but third it seems like I'm doing the same thing as in 2nd instance because 2nd already contains the same $httpClient.

Comment: *How do you call $httpClient, class parameter or?*
*I don't know what you're asking here.*

I'm new with PHP so I don't know terminology well. You know how in function function foo($bar);  $bar is called "function argument"?
Is the in case of class, like $yt = new Zend_Gdata($httpClient) $httpClient called "class argument"?
I'm asking because I would like to read some theory behind that, but not sure what to search for.

Comment: Only instantiate one `Zend_Gdata_YouTube` object. If you plan on doing more than one thing on it, use whichever constructor has the most arguments for what you're doing. So if you will be doing anonymous things **and** authorized things, use the authorization constructor.

Comment: A class cannot be "called" so there are no "class arguments". When you call `new NameOfClassThing($arg1, $arg2)`, you are calling the **constructor** of the **class** "`NameOfClassThing`". The values you pass are used as the arguments in the constructor.